# Excel - Find the Top 'X' amount of values based on criteria

Tags: excel

I am trying to solve the following problem.

I want to find the top 'X' amount of values based on the specified criteria.

I found the following code online, but i am having trouble understanding it / modifying it to include if statements.

```
=INDEX(DATA!B:B,MATCH(1,INDEX((DATA!B:B=LARGE(DATA!B:B,ROWS(U$1:U1)))*(COUNTIF(U$1:U1,DATA!B:B)=0),),0))
```

Data!B:B refers to my column where i am storing my values.

I have a list of names in Column C and a list of states in column A.

Basically, i want to only show the top values, for those that are in a specific state and name.

```
State   Random Value    Name
VIC     $99,581.00      Dan
WA      $95,713.00      Jim
NT      $93,469.00      Bob
NSW     $93,259.00      Cat
NSW     $92,425.00      Dan
ACT     $89,513.00      Hat
NSW     $88,727.00      Potato
NSW     $86,612.00      Fence
```

Edit*

I forgot to mention that i have tried using a pivot table, but my main issue is that i dont want people or similar strings grouped together. When i created my pivot table it grouped the two strings together and summed them. I want distinct entries for each.

Comment: What excel are you using?

Comment: I am using professional plus 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$9,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($1:$9)/(($A$1:$A$9="NSW")*($C$1:$C$9="Dan")),ROW(1:1)))
```

[image]

The you can drag it down as many rows as you want and it will bring the next highest amount that meets the criteria.

The Row(1:1) will increase by one for every row it is drug down, thus bring the 2nd then the third highest.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it should work. I will test it out now and let you know my findings.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I was on the verge of solving this my self. I was utilizing the conditioning in the wrong way. Thank you so much for your clarification and well structured solution.

Comment: I am getting memory issues when i am trying to use this formula more than once.

For example, when i am trying to caculate the top amounts for each state. It says excel has run out of memory and cannot calculate the formulas.

Comment: @DanielleinaD what is the formula you are using? And how many formulas are you using?

Comment: It diddnt save my formula, but it was the exact same as yours, except i added a 3rd critieria to filter by as well.

It would allow me to create 1, but when i tried to update my calculations it gave me that error / message.

Comment: @DanielleinaD Make sure you are not using full column deferences. It should not have been a problem with three.

Comment: So it will not work references an entire column? i will have to have the actual range?


Is there not a way to make this dynamic to work with any data sheet size ( in terms of column length)

Comment: =INDEX(DATA!$B1:$B63,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(DATA!1:63)/((DATA!$A1:$A63=$E5)*(DATA!$C1:$C63=$E3)*(DATA!$D1:$D63=$C17)),ROW(1:1)))

=INDEX(DATA!$B1:$B63,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(DATA!1:63)/((DATA!$A1:$A63=$E9)*(DATA!$C1:$C63=$E3)*(DATA!$D1:$D63=$C17)),ROW(1:1)))

I am also getting an error where when i have two formulas, they are  both returning the same value, even though they are using different references ( ie top 10 by state)
E5 and E9 are my references to the state names

Comment: The aggregate function uses an array so it will iterate through all 1.04 million rows for each criteria. And create arrays in memory to find the largest.  You need to limit it to a row number just big enough to cover the largest it will be. @DanielleinaD

Comment: @DanielleinaD You need to make sure that the data ranges are absolute.  You are not making the rows absolute `=INDEX(DATA!$B$1:$B$63,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(DATA!$1:$63)/((DATA!$A1:$A63=$E5)*(DATA!$C$1:$C$63=$E3)*(DATA!$D$1:$D$63=$C17)),ROW(1:1)))`.  Also if you are getting the same value it may be because it is the same value.  Try using just the aggregate part and see what it is returning, it will help narrow the problem `=AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(DATA!$1:$63)/((DATA!$A1:$A63=$E5)*(DATA!$C$1:$C$63=$E3)*(DATA!$D$1:$D$63=$C17)),ROW(1:1))`

Comment: It is actually returning the wrong amount. my C17 check is a 50/50 check, and it is actually returning the opposite to what i am telling to make sure it =.
So i am basically doing that test to see if its a car or bike. I am saying i only want to return the cars which match. but its giving me the value for the bike that matches.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by column B and pick the top x rows. You can use an advanced sort if you need to.

Comment: This would normally work, but id like to be able to take the top 10 of each criteria which i specify, like take the top 10 for each state etc. Which is why id like to have it done via formula so i dont have to keep changing filters when i am trying to grab the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Pivot table on that data - it is very easy once you get the hang of it. Here's a link that shows you how: [Excel Pivot Table Filters Top X](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-filters-top10.html)

Once you get the hang of it, it is easier to change the criteria as well. If you have data that has say another column with cities in it, then not only can you filter by states, but if you want top 5 states AND top 5 cities inside each state, then that's easy to get as well. You will need to just learn to play around with the labels/column headers.

EDIT: Based on your comment to previous answers, and don't want to be feeling stuck on Pivots, but how about this:
If you want to sort by State, then row label 1 = Random Value, and row label 2 = State; sort Largest to Smallest on cell E1.
[image: RV - State]

If you want to sort by Name, then row label 1 is still = Random Value, and row label 2 = Name; sort Largest to Smallest on cell E1 as well.
[image: RV - Name]

If you want to filter by Name and State, then Row Label 1 = Random Value, RL2 = Name, RL3 = State. Use Sort on Row Label 1, and filters on Name and State.
[image: RV - Name&State]

Comment: The pivot table was my initial thought as well, however it doesnt seem to be able to count distinct entries.

By that i mean, I want to be able to count the entries of two people with the same name as different. Currently the pivot table will combine them if they share a string.

Comment: How do you identify that they are different people? Are they from a different state? E.g. Dan from NSW and Dan from VIC? In that case, you can maybe have a first row label of State and a second row label of Name? Then use the pivot sorting/topX functions by Name?

Comment: At the moment, i am simply only distinguishing by their dollar amount. I have some projects which are much more detailed in scope. But i am just trying to get something basic going first.

If there is two Dan's from NSW, i would just want them sorted by value as individual entries. At the moment it just sums their values together.

Comment: If so, then @El-Kurto's answer is complete? Put filters on the given table, and sort "Random Value" column in decreasing order? (Apologies if I am not able to completely grasp your problem)